# Pooling uncorrelated data to increase size of data or not

Tags: machine-learning, pooling

I have a generic ML "theory" question, and I haven't been able to find any papers with online search.

**Background**

My area is financial price prediction, and this is an area where ML generally works very poorly due to very high noise to signal.

In  traditional areas like say image recognition of classification of cats vs dogs or buses vs cars, a cat will kind of look like 100 other cats and a bus will kind of look like 100 other buses.

But in the markets, almost 50% of patterns will not only fail out-of-sample, but will give the opposite interpretation, i.e. if X is positively correlated to Y in-sample, then it is not surprising to get X as negatively correlated to Y out-of-sample.

**Problem**

My problem is as follows: suppose I have a set of markets that are largely uncorrelated to each other, e.g. S&P, Lean Hogs, Crude Oil, Gold, Sugar, etc., and my problem is to predict the future prices.

I have two choices:

(a) **Option 1: use an different ML model for each uncorrelated market separately.**

*Potential benefits*: since each market is uncorrelated, there is no justification for the same ML model to work everywhere.

*Potential issues*: Data becomes very limited if each market is predicted independently. Challenges of getting a robust model due to limited data. Example: a typical market's history data (assuming daily) will only 4000 days from 16 years, and the history data of interest (e.g. big move days) could be even smaller say 500-1000 days from 16 years.

(b) **Option 2: pool data from all uncorrelated market and create a uniform ML model.**

*Potential benefits*: more robust fitting of the model as the size of the data gets multiplied

*Potential issues*: the ML model will likely either end up working good only on a subset of markets and poorly on other subsets, or likely weak across all markets.

**Question**

While I can obviously do various cross-validations to find out whether Option 1 or Option 2 above is better for my problem, I wanted to ask :

(a) are there any theoretical or academic works that have explored the idea of pooling uncorrelated data to increase the sample size of data?

(b) any specific theoretic or academic work around when option 1 vs option 2 is better?

Thanks.